# Help with some ExternalStorage limitations

Tags: serviceexecute, externalstorage, dropbox

I'm using Dropbox through v12.1's new [ExternalStorageObject](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalStorageObject.html) and friends:

[image]

It's great functionality, however I would really like to **list the objects in a given path**, either explicitly or with an iterator (like the old S3Link). *Is there any way to do this?*

**Notes:**

- I'm running v12.1 on MacOS with a professional Dropbox account authenticated.
- In order to set `$ExternalStorageBase` in your init.m, you need to `Unprotect` it first :/
- There doesn't seem to be any multithreading on the upload and download for very large files or directories. I haven't found any workarounds for this.

Comment: The second might be a bug. `$ExternalStorageBase` is a paclet autoloading symbol (why?), and so it has `OwnValues` and is `Protected`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Dropbox functionality for external storage comes from a Service Connection to Dropbox. You can list files on a path in Dropbox by using ServiceExecute.